# 回答がプラス票の多い順に表示されないのはなぜですか？

Tags: サポート

たとえば [コマンドが終了したら音を鳴らしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/230/%E3%82%B3%E3%83%9E%E3%83%B3%E3%83%89%E3%81%8C%E7%B5%82%E4%BA%86%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89%E9%9F%B3%E3%82%92%E9%B3%B4%E3%82%89%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84) のように多数の回答が付いているものだとわかりやすいのですが、回答が投票によるスコア降順ではなく、最終編集日時の降順で並んでいるように見えます。

[ツアーページ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)には

> よい回答にはプラス票が入り、最上位に浮上します。
>   一番役に立つ回答をすぐに読めるように、点数が高いものほど先頭に表示されます。

と書かれていますが、そのようにはなっていません。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

票数以外のソート順も選択できるので、そのせいではないでしょうか？

[image: sample]

- **アクティブ**
  回答の作成・更新日時が新しい順
- **古い順**
  回答の作成・更新日時が古い順
- **票**
  投票によるスコアが高い順（[回答が1ページに収まる場合に限り](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/18938/286934)、同スコアの回答はランダム）

また上記の設定に関わらず、質問者が承認（緑のチェックマーク）した回答は一番上に表示されます。

> 回答が投票によるスコア降順ではなく、最終編集日時の降順で並んでいるように見えます。

とのことなので、「アクティブ」を選択しているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: なるほど、確かにアクティブが選ばれていたようです。慣れておらず気づいていませんでした。大変失礼いたしました。
となると、これは誤報告ということでこの質問ごと削除すべきケースでしょうか？

Comment: 他にも疑問に思う方がいらっしゃるかもしれませんし、Q&Aとして残しておけばいいと思います。そのままでいいかとも思いましたが、質問文とタイトルも質問形式に変えてみました。